# PHP Comparing two dates but Hours not functioning correctly

Tags: php, date

I'm having an issue with my code not displaying the correct difference between dates. The Days Minutes and Seconds all work correctly but the Hours seem to be displayed the subtracted amount and not the remainder if that makes sense at all.

For example, using these dates
2171167 = 2013-05-18 00:00:00 - 2013-04-22 20:53:53

I receive the following output
25 days 19:06:07

```
$date_one = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date_two = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, 5, 18, 2013));
$Difference = abs(strtotime($date_two) - strtotime($date_one));

$Days = date("d", $Difference);
//$Hours = date("H", $Difference); Why does this NOT WORK???
$Minutes = date("i", $Difference);
$Seconds = date("s", $Difference);
```

If you could please tell me why the second "Hours" variable i have commented out is not working i would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Is the commented out line not returning 19? What is it returning?

Comment: It is returning 19 and i believe it should be 3 in this scenario.

Comment: Yeah, the remainder in the day at 20:53:53 would be 03:06:07

Comment: `$Difference` is being treated as a time in GMT, and `date("H")` is converting to your local time zone.

Comment: Even with date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); declared?

Comment: Then it's converting to the LA timezone instead of your local timezone. But the argument to `date()` is always a Unix timestamp, which is UTC.

Comment: Yes, even with `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` declared `$Difference` is not treated as GMT, `$Difference` is the number of seconds since Jan 1st 1970, 00:00:00 GMT (or Dec 31st 1969 17:00:00 PDT if you prefer). And this time span is the same regardles what your timezone settings are.

Comment: This is why PHP has a `DateInterval` class to deal with time periods.

Comment: Perfect, that explains it! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2013-05-18 00:00:00');
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2013-04-22 20:53:53');

$result = $date1->diff($date2);

echo $result->format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
?>
```

Shows:

```
00-0-25 03:6:7
```

---

To split into variables:

```
list($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second) = explode('-', $result->format('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%i-%s'));

var_dump($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second);
```

Shows:

```
string(2) "00"
string(1) "0"
string(2) "25"
string(2) "03"
string(1) "6"
string(1) "7"
```

Comment: I've seen this before but i was unable to break up the results into their own variable so i could use them each separately later. Long term i could not use this. If it is possible to get the hours, minutes and seconds each into their own variables using this, it would work perfectly for me.

Comment: You can use `$Hours = $result->format('%H')` to get just the hours.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the hours syntax.

```
<?php
    $date_one = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $date_two = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, 5, 18, 2013));
    $Difference = round(strtotime($date_two) - strtotime($date_one));

    $Days = date("d", $Difference);
    $Hours = date("H", $Difference);
    echo $Hours = $Difference / 60;
    $Minutes = date("i", $Difference);
    $Seconds = date("s", $Difference);
?>
```

Comment: That's the total number of hours, not just the hours within a day.

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong first date use below code to your actual answer

```
$date_one = "2013-04-22 20:53:53"; //date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date_two = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, 5, 18, 2013));
$Difference = abs(strtotime($date_two) - strtotime($date_one));

echo "<br> dif ->".date('d H:i:s',$Difference);

echo "<br> day -> ".$Days = date("d", $Difference);
echo "<br> Hours -> ".$Hours = date("H", $Difference); 
echo "<br> Minutes -> ".$Minutes = date("i", $Difference);
echo "<br> Seconds -> ".$Seconds = date("s", $Difference);
```

**:OUTPUT:**

dif -> 26 03:06:07

```
day -> 26
Hours -> 03
Minutes -> 06
Seconds -> 07
```

Comment: My output is dif ->25 22:06:07
 day -> 25
 Hours -> 22

Comment: may be your apache server time is different then mine